# Blocking thread interrupt

Tags: c++, multithreading, blocking

The following process function reads data off a queue and processes it. The `wait_and_pop` function of `masterQueue` performs a blocking call. Therefore, control does not move ahead until there exists data on the queue that can be read.

```
class Context
{
  void launch()
  {
   boost::thread thread1(boost::bind(&Context::push,this ) );
   boost::thread thread2(boost::bind(&Context::process,this ) );

   std::cout<<"Joining Thread1"<<std::endl;
   thread1.join();
   std::cout<<"Joining Thread2"<<std::endl;
   thread2.join();
  }

  void process()
  {
    Data data;
    while(status)
    {
      _masterQueue.wait_and_pop(data); //Blocking Call

      //Do something with data
    }
  }

  void push()
  {
    while(status)
    {
       //Depending on some internal logic, data is generated
      _masterQueue.push(data);
    }
  }
};
```

status is a boolean(in global scope). This boolean is set to true by default. It is only changed to false when a signal is caught such as SIGINT, SIGSESV etc. In such a case, the while loop is exited and the program can be exited safely.

```
bool status = true;

void signalHandler(int signum)
{
  std::cout<<"SigNum"<<signum;
  status = false;
  exit(signum);
}

int main()
{
  signal(SIGABRT, signalHandler);
  signal(SIGINT, signalHandler);
  signal(SIGSEGV, signalHandler);
  Context context;
  context.launch();
}
```

Since, no new data is pushed by thread2 when a signal is thrown, control in thread1 is stuck at

```
_masterQueue.wait_and_pop(data);
```

How do I force this blocking call to be interrupted?

1. Is it possible to implement this without changing the internal workings of wait_and_pop
2. Placing a timeout is not an option, since data may arrive on the queue once in a couple of hours or multiple times a second
3. Do I push a specific type of data on receiving a signal, e.g INT_MAX/INT_MIN, which the process function is coded to recognise and it exits the loop.

Comment: Does not the thread ends when you exit? Why unblock it?

Answer (score 0):

Timeout actually is your answer
You break your loop on getting an answer or having an interrupt

You could also spoof things a bit by having the inturrupt push a noop to the queue

Comment: I understand the pushing to the queue solution. My requirements do not allow me to place a timeout. However, I'm interested in knowing how and where the timeout code can be placed

Comment: If you timeout after 3 seconds, and input comes in 1 second, it is the same as no timeout.  If input comes after 5 seconds, you timeout once and wait again for 2 seconds.  The only impact is if input comes in right wnen you are iterating, but thats negible. Set your timeout to your max tolerance for waiting for the inturrupt to occur.  The rest you should be able to figure out.

Comment: This class is generic. It is used in multiple situations to read and process data sequentially. The timeout value will therefore be specific to each situation. However, how I see it, I cant help but hardcode this value

Comment: The timeout is ONLY related to the lag of responding to the interupt and the performance hit of coming in and out of the block

Answer (score 0):

You can try to `.interrupt()` thread when need to finish it.

If `.wait_and_pop()` uses standard boost mechanism for wait(condition variable or like), it will definitely be interrupted even in blocked state via throwing *boost::thread_interrupted* exception. If your *masterQueue* class is reliable wrt exceptions, then such interruption is safe.

Comment: It uses a condition variable. Do you mean something like thread1.interrupt()

Comment: How do I access thread1 and thread2 in signalHandler? Do I make them data members of Context?

Comment: Yes, you should make threads available to signalHandler, and call `thread1.interrupt()` and `thread2.interrupt()` from it.